# Create a subscribed EKCalendar on iCloud?

Tags: ios, icalendar, eventkit

I'd like to create a subscribed calendar on iOS but have it stored in iCloud so that it will be visible on the user's other devices. I see how to create an iCloud EKCalendar but I don't see any way to tell it what the subscribed url is.

Is this just not possible yet via the SDK?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant create the subscribed calendar on iOS. Checkout the **Notes** in the [support forum](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5029)

Hope this helps.